# $\vec{B}\cdot \text{d}\vec{s}$ is always zero but in electromagnetic induction not always zero

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

We know integration of $\vec{B}\cdot \text{d}\vec{s}$ over closed surface is zero because magnetic monopoles don't exist but in the following electromagnetic induction unit they use the same $\vec{B}\cdot \text{d}\vec{s}$ (this time not equated to zero) in the questions to calculate the answers....I know it's change of magnetic flux they talk about here.....but for my satisfaction can someone elaborate?

Comment: Gauss's law for magnetism only applies to integrals over _closed_ surfaces.

Comment: All i am saying is m(in) is always zero (m is magnetic moment of a monopole) so is it not contradictory to the results in EMI unit

Answer (score 4):

Gauss' law for magnetism does *not* say that $\vec B \cdot d\vec s = 0$.  It says that if you have a closed surface and you integrate the outward flux *over the entire thing*, the integral will be equal to zero.

In discussions about magnetic induction, $\vec B \cdot d\vec s$ is integrated over an *open* surface, and so the result will generically be nonzero.  There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 0):

So the Maxwell equations in SI units state that
$$
\nabla\times \vec E = -{\partial\vec B\over \partial t}.
$$
We can integrate this equation over a *non-closed* area to find that actually,
$$
\iint_\mathcal S d\vec A~\cdot (\nabla\times \vec E) = -\iint_\mathcal S d\vec A~\cdot {\partial\vec B\over \partial t}.$$
By Stokes' theorem the left hand side simplifies; the right hand side can simplify slightly if we pull the time derivative out and define the flux of the magnetic field through the surface as $\Phi_\text B = \int d\vec A \cdot \vec B.$ So this amounts to: $$\int_{\partial \mathcal S} d\vec\ell\cdot \vec E = - \frac{d\Phi_\text B}{dt}.$$You want to say "shouldn't the right hand side be zero for any closed surface?" and the answer is "yes, but the surface is not closed." We could *make* a closed surface by stitching together two surfaces with the same boundary but opposite orientation, $\partial \mathcal S_1 = -\partial \mathcal S_2,$ but then we see -- wonder of wonders, miracle of miracles -- that the two integrals on the left-hand side are exactly opposite and cancel out. (If the boundaries are not chosen to have opposite direction then the normal vector changes sign discontinuously at the "seam" between the two surfaces, and you cannot use Gauss's law.)

In fact this is a very deep relationship that we need for mathematical consistency, which we can observe even more directly by looking at the divergence of that Maxwell equation: we know that the divergence of any curl is zero and we find that $$0 = -{\partial\over \partial t}\nabla\cdot \vec B.$$This means that the equation-as-written only works for a stationary distribution of magnetic monopoles -- and this implies that it must be a *spatially constant* distribution if we combine it with the principle that there is no preferred reference frame for electromagnetism: any variation in space would appear to be a variation at one location in time in a different reference frame. Most likely if one wanted to accomodate magnetic monopoles $\rho_\text B$ one would need to define a corresponding monopole current $J_\text B$ satisfying ${\partial\rho_\text B\over\partial t}=-\nabla\cdot J_\text B,$ and then our equations would have to say $$\nabla\cdot\vec B = \kappa_0~\rho_\text B\\
\nabla\times \vec E = -{\partial\vec B\over\partial t} - \kappa_0~\vec J_\text B.$$This way if we took the divergence of both sides we would get zero from the monopole-charge continuity equation, just like we do for the electric-charge continuity equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Sigma$ be one surface in the three-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^3$. Define the magnetic flux through $\Sigma$ as the function

$$\phi(t,\Sigma)=\int_\Sigma \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t)\cdot \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x}) 
 d\Sigma$$

where $\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x})$ is the normal vector of $\Sigma$ at the point $\mathbf{x}\in \Sigma$.

It so happens that if $\Sigma$ is a *closed* surface, enclosing a volume $M$, in other words, $\Sigma$ is the bounding surface of $M$, which wewrite as $\Sigma = \partial M$, then Stoke's theorem states that

$$\phi(t,\Sigma)=\int_{\Sigma}\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t)\cdot \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x}) d\Sigma=\int_{\partial M}\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t)\cdot \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x}) d\Sigma=\int_M \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t) d^3\mathbf{x}.$$

Now, it turns out that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$. Thus,

$$\phi(t,\Sigma)=0,\quad\text{when $\Sigma$ is closed by virtue of Stoke's theorem.}$$

When $\Sigma$ is not closed you can't use Stoke's theorem to pass to the integral of the divergence, and $\phi(t,\Sigma)$ can be anything.

By the way, you might as well ask why $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$. This is the real statement that says that magnetic monopoles do not exist and is one fact of observation.

From one historical viewpoint, I believe people started with Biot-Savart law and found $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})=0$ to be true in the static case, and together with the fact that no one observed magnetic monopoles, extended this to the general dynamic case.